# Cannot Upload a File in an App installed on Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, windows-subsystem-for-android

I'm using a mobile app through windows subsystem for Android. The app is working fine. but when I try to upload a file to that app it will not prompt for opening file manager or storage locations for choosing file. I cannot find what's wrong with Windows Subsystem for Android. Is there any issue with the WSA or other problem.?

I have no idea about what to try.
I need to know the way how to upload the file in wsa App

Comment: What command(s) do you execute for "try to upload a file"?

Comment: i'm not using any command i had tried via UI @Robert

Comment: If you don't use an (adb) command why have used the `adb` tag on your question? Have you tried to check `adb logcat` while "uploading" the file? If something goes wrong there is a high chance that logcat will contain an error message that allows you to identify the prblem.

Comment: @Robert I want to know is there any option with adb that's why I have used `adb` tag

Comment: A quick search would have shown you commands like `adb install <apkfile.apk>` or `adb push somefile /sdcard/`.